# Struts 2 autocompleter not working as dropdown

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

I have a JSP page in which I have use `sx:autocompleter`. It is working but at the time of typing in textbox, suggestions are not coming in dropdown, they are coming as completing the word. Like this

What is the problem here ?

[image]

Comment: **Image** don't describe actual problem but your *Code* will !

Comment: @NeerajJain The actual problem is in struts2-dojo-plugin, which is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag) instead.

> The Autocompleter widget renders a HTML input or select box with.

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <sj:autocompleter
            id="customers"
            name="echo"
            list="%{customers}"
            listValue="name"
            listKey="id"
            selectBox="true"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i write another word which is not in list then it is removing automatically after going to next text box...any solution of this ?

Comment: Try forceValidOption="false"